# what does this expression means in Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
```

What does this line mean in regular expression ? It is used for checking the name,but I don't know how it is doing?

Comment: this is not related to jQuery but to javascript. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: this has nothing to do with jquery. it's a regular expression.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Regex. It matches any number of lowercase characters, uppercase characters or spaces (including an empty string). Google `regular expressions`

Comment: Check here:- http://regex101.com/

Comment: Hey has the stack gone nuts??? Someone's very busy down-voting! Admins, please pay attention!

Comment: Matches every string containing zero or more occurrences of a-zA-Z (lower and uppercase literals) See: http://gravity.tbates.org/reg-101.html

Comment: OP: Good on you for editing your question, however [tag:nsregularexpression] is NOT an appropriate tag for this question, since that tag is specifically for the Apple developer library, not JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's not jQuery. It's [Vanilla JavaScript](http://vanilla-js.com/), a significantly more powerful engine.

In this case, it's a regex literal, made with the intent of checking that a name only contains uppercase or lowercase letters, or spaces.

Comment: why is this getting downvoted? jealousy much?

Comment: +1 for Vanilla JavaScript. great framework. i use it every day :)

Comment: @EliranMalka i guess someone wanted to see his answer at top...

Comment: "powerfun" - one of my better typos!

Answer (score 2):

It's a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), it matches zero or more characters which are letters (either upper or lower case) or spaces

Comment: Strangely, this answer the question so don't hesitate to comment on downvote...

Answer (score 1):

It is a regular expression which allows only alphabets and a space to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

first its a regular expression not jquery, and is of javascript

```
/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/

    it matches all alphabets in lower and upper case from 0 to unlimited times 
    with spaces
```

## [Explained](http://regex101.com/r/dW8yS2)

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to note that this is not just related to JQuery. Rather this is what we call a regular expression.

This is probably a part of a validation routine. This means "allow any letter 'a' to 'z' in lower and upper case and also allow for spaces.

What you need to do is learn regular expressions to understand this code - not JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It is a regular expression.

In this case, it will match a string that begins and ends with 0 or more occurrences of lower case letters, uppercase letters, or white space characters.

There are many ways to use regular expressions, but to give an example:

```
var name = 'John Smith';

/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(name); // true
```